# How can I run Lwjgl in core package

Tags: java, libgdx, lwjgl

It's possible to run as desktop in core package? I tryed to add the lwjgl libs to this package but I can't.

I copyed the code from the desktop package, like this:

```
public static void main (String[] arg) {
    LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.title = "X-Ball";
    cfg.height = 480;
    cfg.width = 640;
    new LwjglApplication(new XBallGame(), cfg);
}
```

but LwjglApplication is missing.

Comment: I guess some of the libs or some imports are missing, but why do you even want to run it from the core Project?

Comment: @Springrbua Because everytime I want to test the project I have to make run as in the desktop package...It's a lazy thing but I want to know if it's possible.

Comment: You could simply create a "Run-Configuration" (if you are using Eclipse) and then run the DesktopVersion straigth from the "Run" button.  
But as you asked, if it is possible, i am almost sure it is, if you add all the neccessary libraries (the one your desktop-project does include) to the core project.

Comment: That is a nice tip but it doesn't work because of the gradle. Gradle won't allow run-configuration, only "external-tools configuration"

Comment: That has nothing to do with gradle, just create a new Run-Configuration, set your Desktop-Class as the mainclass, give it a name and you are done. If you also add it to the favorite-list, you should see it in the drop-down list to and you can run it there

Comment: Worked? Add the solution as an answer then, it may help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing dependencies. I have the same setup:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-desktop:$gdxVersion"
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-controllers-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
```

These are the dependencies you need on your Core project.

Also make sure to register your main class in the Core project Gradle build file.

```
project.ext.mainClassName = "com.yourpackage.game.MainClass."
```

However may I recommend if you only want a Desktop project, make a new one, a single Gradle project, and import all the dependencies yourself as I showed above.

It'll make your project a lot less clustered.